# Setting FetchMode in native Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to set the fetch mode on my hibernate mappings to be eager in some cases, and lazy in others. I have my default (set through the hbm file) as lazy="true". How do I override this setting in code? MyClass has a set defined of type MyClass2 for which I want to set the FetchMode to EAGER.

Currently, I have something like:

```
Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
MyClass c = (MyClass)session.get(MyClass.class, myClassID);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like this: (code off the top of my head)

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(MyClass.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("id", myClassId));
crit.setFetchMode("myProperty", FetchMode.EAGER);
MyClass myThingy = (MyClass)crit.uniqueResult();
```

I believe that FetchMode.JOIN or FetchMode.SELECT should be used instead of FetchMode.EAGER, though.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not using Criteria there's also the `JOIN FETCH` keyword that will eagerly load the association specified by the join.

```
session.createQuery("select p from Parent p join fetch p.children c")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a static `initialize(Object)` method in the `Hibernate` main class. You could use that to force loading of your collection:

```
MyClass c = (MyClass)session.get(MyClass.class, myClassID);
Hibernate.initialize(c.getMySetOfMyClass2());
```

However, a default value of lazy fetching is just that: a *default* value. You probably want to override the laziness in the mapping for your particular Set.