# hibernate setting fetch dynamically

Tags: java, hibernate, fetch

I have an entity named Entity with a one to many relation with some children of the type Child set up by this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "child" ) private Set<Child> children;
```

I put `fetch=FetchType.LAZY` because I need it to be as quik as possible whenever I needn't know what children are.

Sometimes, instead I need to get them when I look for some Entity.

In those cases, according to the suggestions of these [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243409/setting-fetchmode-in-native-hibernate), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502898/hibernate-change-fetch-mode-in-runtime), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435304/how-to-override-hibernate-fetching-strategy-at-runtime), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038589/how-to-set-fetch-type-at-runtime-hibernate) questions, I wrote something of the kind:

```
from Entity as ent left join fetch ent.children where /* some conditions */
```

the point is that I get conditions from another class, so I won't use Criteria, unless I find a way to transform a query object of the kind

```
getSession().createQuery("from Entity where /* some conditions */");
```

in a criteria. The problem is that I get the number of records given by the join, so one for each empty set of children and one for each Child.

What I need, is just the instance (or the list of instances, according to the fact that I call `getResultList()` on the list) of the Entity where the set is properly populated by the instance's children.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a feature: Imagine you would fetch your Entity without it's children and later persist it again, Hibernate would delete all the children. Because it can not determine weather you did or did not delete them "yourself".

What you might want to try is fetching a Tuple (and in so doing only select the table columns you are interested in) instead of the whole entity. You can only access lazy fields (properly) within an active transaction.